# Drill down charts in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, charts

I'm trying to get a set of reports running in an (VB) ASP.NET project and as part of that I'd like to display some charts visualising the data. I'm able to get charts generated, and have used Flotr, Plotr, Google Charts, and some CSS techniques at various times as I've experimented with this.

Ideally, what I'm trying to achieve is having the individual elements (slices in a pie chart, or bars in a bar graph) be clickable, to drill-down to a lower level of data using that parent element as a filter. The closest I've seen is some tutorials on doing this with the ReportViewer control but only linking through text elements, which I've already achieved on my own.

Is this something I'd have to turn to Flash for, as I'd prefer to avoid that where possible. If it's the only solution though, then I may need to resign myself to it.

It's probably warranting a mention that all the data is stored in a database, so any chart generation is done dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at jqChart, a plugin for jQuery -- there doesn't seem to be any non-creative limit to what you can do with that plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQchart

Answer (score 2):

a clickable image map would probably do the trick...

...or you could just buy Dundas

Answer (score 2):

I agree on the image map idea if you build it yourself.

If you want it out of the box, [Dundas Charts](http://www.dundas.com) and probably some of the other good charting tools support this type of drill down functionality.